# Openldap : overlay accesslog not found

Tags: overlay, openldap, access-log

I am trying to configure accesslog. I have changed the slapd.conf file and trying to test using slaptest but i am getting error while executing **slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf**.

slapd.conf configuration:

```
  # See slapd.conf(5) for details on configuration options.  
  # This file should NOT be world readable.
   include     /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
   include     /etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
   include     /etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
   include     /etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
   .
   .     
   modulepath /usr/lib/openldap/
   moduleload accesslog.la

   overlay accesslog
   logdb "cn=accesslog"
   logops writes
   logsuccess TRUE
```

I am getting error at overlay accesslog

```
  overlay "accesslog" not found
  slaptest: bad configuration file!
```

Am I missing something..?

Comment: Does `/usr/lib/openldap/accesslog.la` exist?

Comment: yeah .. accesslog.la is present in /usr/lib/openldap directory..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue on my own. I have not compiled the openldap with --enable overlay.

To solve this issue

- i have downloaded the openldap src
- ./configure --enable-overlays (***./configure [options] [variable=value ...]***)
- Now modify the slapd.conf to load accesslog.la and execute slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf. Now you wont find any error.
- restart the slapd.